# grep only words that have at least two same syllables

Tags: unix, grep, cpu-word

Is it possible to use grep for this?  i want grep words like "hahaha" or "cocoa" or "19931992".

i have something like this:

```
egrep "\s+((([a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9])){2}\S*)\s+" file
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool to convert numbers to syllables.

Comment: i have to do it with regex :/

Comment: Do you really mean "syllable"? Should it match "ffff" for example?

Answer (score 3):

This will serve what you want

```
egrep "(\w{2}).*\1" file
```

Please check output in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRxh.png).

Comment: but it grep words like 9227 because of 22 or http... i need grep only syllable not two same letters... can you fix that problem?

Comment: i have to change it a little bit because .* takes all characters so i change it like this:  egrep "(\w{2})[a-zA-Z0-9]*\1"   and its work good for me :)